# Azure Two Different View On refresh

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-sql-database

Not sure what terms to search or look for but I have a website that is hosted on Azure. Everytime i Refresh i get different values/Views out.

Might Start with this.

[image]

Then i refresh. I get this

[image]

Then if i Start the service from visual studio, connecting to the azure database. I get. The normal view which looks like

[image]

Any Idea what could be the problem?

Comment: Can you post more details about how this view is generated? My *guess* currently is that this some kind of feature/bug in your application logic - something which somehow is occurring in production, but not in dev.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing more about your application, and without seeing any code from it, I'm going to take a wild guess and assume you're showing screen shots from an asp.net application, and that you're running more than one instance of your web role.

If that's indeed the case, you might be running into the case where each web role instance is using in-proc session state, meaning you'd have different session state on each instance. There's no State Server for session state in Windows Azure.

If this is the case, then take a look at AppFabric Cache, which is essentially caching-as-a-service. The caching team also built an asp.net session state provider that sits atop the AppFabric Cache, and provides a consistent session cache across all of your instances. the [Windows Azure Platform Training Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=413E88F8-5966-4A83-B309-53B7B77EDF78&displaylang=en) has a lab called **Building Windows Azure Applications with the Caching Service** - this will walk you through setting up and using the cache for session state.